# How do I adjust the video quality from the camera in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I want to upload a video into server from my app, now I can upload small size video's, but in the case of larger size the video uploading is not done.How can I do this.

I found a reason that the 2 minutes video has the size 300 mb, so how can I reduce the size of the video with out losing the quality

Please somebody help me..

Here is my code for video taking

```
  private async void TakeVideo_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakeVideoSupported)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera avaialble.", "OK");
            return;
        }

        var _file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakeVideoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreVideoOptions
        {
            Name = "gtsvideo.mp4",
            Directory = "GTSVideos",
        });

        if (_file == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            _path = _file.Path;

            using (var _streamReader = new StreamReader(_file.GetStream()))
            {
                var _array = default(byte[]);                 

                using (MemoryStream _memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    _streamReader.BaseStream.CopyTo(_memoryStream);                  

                    _array = _memoryStream.ToArray();                        

                    if (await DisplayAlert(App._confirmation, "It may take few Minutes..,Do you want to save the video?", "Yes", "Cancel"))
                    {
                        FileUploadAsync(_array, false);
                        activity_Indicator.IsVisible = true;
                        activity_Indicator.IsRunning = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }



   public async void FileUploadAsync(byte[] fileUpload, bool IsImage)
    {

        APIResponse _response = await App.DataManager.UpdateFilesAsync(_task.ID, fileUpload, IsImage);

        if (IsImage == false)
         {                
           await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(5000);
         }

        if (_response != null)
        {
            activity_Indicator.IsRunning = false;

            if (IsImage)
            {
                DependencyService.Get<IAlertPlayer>().AlertMessege("Image upload successfully");
            }
            else
            {
                DependencyService.Get<IAlertPlayer>().AlertMessege("Video upload successfully");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            DisplayAlertMessage();
        }
    }
```

UploadVideo

```
   public async Task<APIResponse> UpdateFilesAsync(int id, byte[] file, bool IsImage)
    {
        Url _url = new Url(BaseURL).AppendPathSegment("tasks/UploadFiles");

        _url.QueryParams["ID"] = id;

        return await Service.POSTFILE<APIResponse>(_url, file, IsImage);
    }


    public async Task<T> POSTFILE<T>(Url url, byte[] uploadFile, bool IsImage)
    {
        try
        {
            using (MultipartFormDataContent _content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                ByteArrayContent _filecontent = new ByteArrayContent(uploadFile);

                if (IsImage)
                {
                    _filecontent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                    {
                        FileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".png"
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    _filecontent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                    {
                        FileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".mp4"
                    };
                }

                _content.Add(_filecontent);

                using (HttpResponseMessage _response = await Client.PostAsync(url, _content))
                {
                     string _result = await _response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(_result);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        return default(T);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: Unless you implement some fancy lossless compression code yourself, you don't. You get what the operating system of your phone gives you.